# Why are classes like SHA1Managed, SHA256Managed hidden from my Intellisense?

Tags: c#, .net-core, hash, cryptography, intellisense

When I go to the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace, I can only see `SHA1`, `SHA256`, `HMACSHA1` etc classes there.

But actually, there is a `SHA1Managed` class, as well as `SHA256Managed`, which I don't see? When I write it out manually - everything works as expected.

Is this hidden intentionally? And what's the difference between simply instancing a managed version of those, versus for example calling their factory methods (`SHA1.Create()` or `SHA256.Create()`)? Are they the same thing?

Comment: You don't by some chance have the "Hide Advanced Members" option selected in your Intellisense settings do you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever hey, thank you, I just checked and no - it's off. (Options -> Text -> C# -> General)

Comment: I don't know why you would use the constructors or implementation methods of the management classes. The direct usage of these classes are, if you ask me, implementation mistakes. You would want to use `Create()` so the system can select the best / fastest implementation available. Note that the managed classes are software only, generally you'd e.g. want to use the native SHA-256 instructions of Intel compatible CPU's with SHA acceleration.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what do you mean the managed classes are software? Aren't they compiled in a managed environment (using managed libraries and etc)? Versus `.Create()` which supposedly uses the native unmanaged code? And how is this unmanaged code accessed? Is it via COM? Or P/Invoke? A book I'm reading mentioned the use of `SHA1Managed`, but nowhere did it explain the difference in using that versus .Create. If you could also share where it states that `.Create()` does what you're describing, that' be awesome as well!

Comment: @SpiritBob those managed classes don't use hardware acceleration (as Intels AES-NI does) therefor it's "software only cryptography"

Answer (score 1):

Can't give you an answer for the weird IntelliSense problem but have a look at the [SHA1](http://%20https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/System/Security/Cryptography/SHA1.cs,105) and [SHA1Managed](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/System/Security/Cryptography/SHA1Managed.cs,11) implementations. SHA1 is just a base class. The implementation is exactly the same in this case. It has something to do with the [FIPS certification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/fips-140-validation). Managed versions don't use the native crypto libraries and therefor are not FIPS certified. There is a registry setting (`FipsAlgorithmPolicy`) for customers which enforces FIPS compliance. If the registry setting is turned on you can't use the managed classes.

In your case it does not make any difference if you instanciate `SHA1Managed` or use `SHA1.Create()`. But it does make a difference if you need to meet the FIPS certification.

Comment: Are the native crypto libraries P/Invoked into? As they are unmanaged code?  I don't think COM is involved here.

Comment: The ones I know are invoked through the CNG API (Application layer -> CNG API layer -> CNG Provider layer -> Kernel). Just open any [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/fips-140-validation#modules-used-by-windows) policy to see further information